# Bind input field to grid component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-binding

How can I synchronize the value of the `SearchFilter` to the `FilterGrid` so that I can filter the data (see code below)? I am having an issue with the field clearing-out the value as I am typing. There must be an issue to the way I am using the state hooks.

The problem is probably attributed to the way I am calling `onChange` inside of the `handleOnChange` function that resides in `SearchFilter`. I passed an `onChange` "listener" as a property to the filter so that I can access the value outside of the filter.

Not sure if this is not the correct way, because binding the value directy to the search field within the grid gave me this warning:

> *"Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component."*

---

Here is a link to a live sandbox:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-ui-search-d4073?file=/src/App.jsx

### App.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import FilterGrid from "./components/FilterGrid";
import jsonData from "./data/data.json";

const fetchData = () => Promise.resolve(jsonData);

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then((json) => setData(json));
  }, []);

  const columns = [
    { key: "nameField", field: "name", title: "Name" },
    { key: "ageField", field: "age", title: "Age" }
  ];

  return <FilterGrid data={data} columns={columns} />;
};

export default App;
```

### FilterGrid.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SearchFilter from "./SearchFilter";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";

const FilterGrid = (props) => {
  const { data, columns } = props;
  const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setFilterValue(value);
    console.log("Value changed...");
  };

  const applyFilter = (records) =>
    records.filter((record) =>
      Object.values(record).some((value) => `${value}`.includes(filterValue))
    );

  const toolbar = () => (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "flex-end"
      }}
    >
      <SearchFilter
        listeners={{
          onChange: handleChange
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );

  console.log("Changed filter:", filterValue);

  return (
    <div>
      <MaterialTable
        data={applyFilter(data)}
        columns={columns}
        components={{
          Toolbar: toolbar
        }}
        options={{
          search: false
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default FilterGrid;
```

### SearchFilter.jsx

```
import { FormControl, Input } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const SearchFilter = (props) => {
  const {
    listeners: { onChange }
  } = props;

  const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState("");

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setInternalValue(e.target.value);
    onChange(internalValue);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl>
      <Input
        type="search"
        placeholder="Search..."
        onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)}
        value={internalValue}
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default SearchFilter;
```

### data.json

```json
[
  { "name": "Bill", "age": 21 },
  { "name": "Bob", "age": 31 },
  { "name": "Brad", "age": 41 }
]
```

### package.json

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.1",
    "material-table": "1.69.2",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.0"
  }
}
```

### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>React Material UI Search</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

issue is the async nature of setState when you do:

```
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setInternalValue(e.target.value);
    onChange(internalValue);
  };
```

internalValue is still empty once `onChange` is executed (it doesnt wait setInternalValue) to update state.

there are other things to consider. you are duplicating state, which is not good practice. you better keep filter state at `FilterGrid` and pass down as props.

other thing I noticed is that every type on input blurs the input field. That can be avoided if you declare ToolTip outside and don't pass as a component param to `FilterGrid`

**FilterGrid**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SearchFilter from "./SearchFilter";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";

const Toolbar = ({ filterValue, setFilterValue }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      display: "flex",
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "flex-end"
    }}
  >
    <SearchFilter filterValue={filterValue} setFilter={setFilterValue} />
  </div>
);

const FilterGrid = (props) => {
  const { data, columns } = props;
  const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = useState("");

  const applyFilter = (records) =>
    records.filter((record) =>
      Object.values(record).some((value) => `${value}`.includes(filterValue))
    );

  console.log("Changed filter:", filterValue);

  return (
    <div>
      <Toolbar filterValue={filterValue} setFilterValue={setFilterValue} />
      <MaterialTable
        data={applyFilter(data)}
        columns={columns}
        options={{
          search: false
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default FilterGrid;
```

**SearchFilter**

```
import { FormControl, Input } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const SearchFilter = (props) => {
  const { filterValue, setFilter } = props;

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setFilter(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl>
      <Input
        type="search"
        placeholder="Search..."
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        value={filterValue}
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
};

SearchFilter.propTypes = {
  filterValue: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  setFilter: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default SearchFilter;
```

Comment: So there is no way to set the toolbar form the grid via `components.Toolbar = () => (<Toolbar ... />)`?

Comment: I am not aware of. The approach you desire forces a rerender on ToolBar resulting on a blur at SeachField on each user's type.